# Arduino uno spi sck not working

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

I am trying to verify sck output on my arduino uno. I don't have oscilloscope so I loopbacked miso to sck and tried Executing int rx0=SPI.transfer(5) while printing this using Serial.printrx0) it is giving 255.Whether this is expected output?

Comment: I'd expect you'll get all bit with the same value. You can try other SPI_MODES and you probably get 0x00 for two of them..  However you could use loopback between MOSI a MISO (you can expect 1B delay)

Comment: Hi KIIV, THANKS for responding.. I tried all the SPI mode and I got 255 as output, means all the bit as 1 in the byte. Whether it is right result?whether I can say my sck output is normal? Thanks

Comment: You could instead send SCK to T1 (pin 5), configure Timer 1 as a counter, and use it to count the clock pulses.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by KIIV and myself, you can test the SPI port by:

- connecting MOSI to MISO and checking if you receive what you send
- connecting SCK to the timer input T1 and counting the clock pulses.

Below is a sketch that performs both tests:

```cpp
/*
 * Test the SPI port.
 *
 * Connect:
 *   MOSI (11) to MISO (12)
 *   SCK (13) to T1 (5)
 */

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Configure SPI port.
    DDRB |= _BV(PB2)   // SS (digital 10) as output
          | _BV(PB3)   // MOSI (digital 11) as output
          | _BV(PB5);  // SCK (digital 13) as output
    SPCR = _BV(SPE)    // enable port
         | _BV(MSTR);  // master mode

    // Configure Timer 1.
    TCCR1A = 0;          // normal mode
    TCCR1B = _BV(CS10)   // count rising edges of T1 = digital 3
           | _BV(CS11)   // ditto
           | _BV(CS12);  // ditto
}

void loop() {
    TCNT1 = 0;  // clear timer
    uint8_t data = random(256);
    Serial.print(data);
    Serial.print(" -> ");
    SPDR = data;  // send
    delay(1);
    if (bit_is_set(SPSR, SPIF)) {  // transfer complete?
        Serial.println(SPDR);
    } else {
        Serial.println("nothing received");
    }
    Serial.print("    clock pulses: ");
    Serial.println(TCNT1);
    delay(1000);
}
```

It should print:

```
167 -> 167
    clock pulses: 8
241 -> 241
    clock pulses: 8
217 -> 217
    clock pulses: 8
[...]
```